# Why does perf_event_open record miss level when using PERF_SAMPLE_DATA_SRC?

Tags: caching, x86, perf

I'm trying to collect information on where in the memory hierarchy that data associated with a given store/load was retrieved from.

When collecting this information using `perf` and extracting it using `perf script`, I find that many of my samples have something like the following *decoded* data source information:

```
L1 miss|SNP N/A|TLB L2 hit|LCK No
L3 miss|SNP N/A|TLB L1 or L2 hit|LCK No
```

However, I'm confused what it means for sample to have *missed* at a given cache level (e.g., `L1 miss`, `L3 miss`). Shouldn't it have *hit* somewhere, and shouldn't that hit have been reported?

I understand that this information is collected by `perf` via `perf_event_open` using`PERF_SAMPLE_DATA_SRC`.

Looking at the Linux kernel repo, I found the following [commit message](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/d6be9ad6c960f43800a6f118932bc8a5a4eadcd1) suggesting that this understanding is correct:

```
This patch adds PERF_SAMPLE_DATA_SRC.

PERF_SAMPLE_DATA_SRC collects the data source, i.e., where
did the data associated with the sampled instruction
come from. ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've dug up:

1. [Perf code for stringifying data source information.](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/219d54332a09e8d8741c1e1982f5eae56099de85/tools/perf/util/mem-events.c#L297-L310)
2. [Perf struct for holding data source info](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/219d54332a09e8d8741c1e1982f5eae56099de85/include/uapi/linux/perf_event.h#L1049-L1081) ([stored in another struct](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/219d54332a09e8d8741c1e1982f5eae56099de85/tools/perf/util/mem-events.h#L21-L26) that gets passed to the stringification function).
3. [Code for getting the data source information for the x86 architecture.](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/219d54332a09e8d8741c1e1982f5eae56099de85/arch/x86/events/intel/ds.c#L1324-L1337)
4. This code is in line with the tables referenced in "Table 18-87. Memory Access Info Group" of Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 3B (Order Number: 325384-073US). (Specifically the entry for *Memory Auxiliary Info*.)

From the Intel manual and the code comments, it's clear how a sample gets labeled as being a cache miss (i.e., sometimes, it's only known whether or not a sample missed at a certain cache level, but not where it hit). That being said, it's not clear why this happens.